# Virtual attributtes on OpenLdap

Tags: openldap

I'm migrating LDAP from OpenDJ to OpenLDAP and I realize that on OpenDJ it's being used virtual attributes:

*"cn=Virtual Attributes,cn=config"*

There isn't no such thin on OpenLdap, right?

I didn't any information on this subject..

Comment: Similar, but not quite the same, functionality is found in the OpenLDAP [Dynamic directory Services - DDS](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Dynamic%20Directory%20Services) overlay, the "memberof" and "dynamic lists" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating attributes on-the-fly with OpenLDAP requires some code to be written server-side. This is most times not trivial.

Normally this is done by implementing a so-called *overlay* in C which gives best performance. An overlay is kind of a plugin you can configure in per database.

[slapd-sock(5)](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd-sock) was originally a backend but can be configured as overlay and forwards the incoming LDAP operations to an external demon listening on a Unix domain socket. I've implemented module package [slapdsock](https://pypi.org/project/slapdsock/) to implement such an external demon with Python 2.x. Obviously this does not give you real high performance and there are some caveats regarding access control.